# Replacing an image in a database with c# (using UPDATE)

Tags: c#, sql

I have a database with images stored in it and I want to replace those images with new ones. Here is the thing: I have a picturebox and in this picturebox I am downloading an image. This image is the one that I want to use to replace the current image of my databaserow where my column "Id" is 6.
Right now I am trying to do it with UPDATE but it is not working and I am wondering why. Here is my code:

```
     private void buttonReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Insert_Image]";   //name of database
        SqlDataAdapter dA = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);
        DataTable dT = new DataTable();
        dA.Fill(dT);
        int z = dT.Rows.Count + 1;
        int i = 6;

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            byte[] img = null;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

            string strSql = "UPDATE [Insert_Image] SET Picture = " + @img + " WHERE Id  LIKE '" + i + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, cn);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex));
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

My Problem is that something is saved in my database, but whatever I am saving with this code is not the binary-code for an image. I checked my filestream and that is correct as I am using the same filestream I used for uploading to the picturebox. I would be very glad for any help or ideas.

Comment: We are going to need more information.  What is your database schema for starters?

Comment: read about SQL paramaters. Your way is wrong for example with binary data. Code has few in-optimal decisions too

Comment: My database has two columns: Id (which is the primary key) and Picture.
Right now I have 10 rows in this database and in row 6 there is a picture that I want to replace with a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not hard code  value in the query, instead use.

```
        cmd.Parameters.Addnew SqlParameter("@img", img));
```

check this [cheet sheet on SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

```
        string strSql = "UPDATE [tablename] SET Picture=@img WHERE Id  LIKE '%@i%'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@i", i));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: In my answer, I had pointed the two main issues. can you check if it works for you.

Comment: it didn't work, still the same results as I had before

Comment: if the id is your primary key the why use "LIKE '" + i + "'"", this means you will end up updating rows with id 6 and anything that *6* (16,26,66) . you should using WHERE Id = @i

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot! And thanks for the link, I'll read it.